# Multiple service provider on WSO2. SSO with oauth2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have 3 application (microservice spring) configured as service provider. I set the OAuth2 auth. and works perfectly.

Now I want to have a SSO between these 3 application/service providers. How can I configure it? (I want to login to one application/service provider ad re-user the auth with other applications/service provider)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special you need to configure to have SSO between those 3 applications. As 3 of them are registered as service providers in WSO2 Identity Server, they will automatically SSO between them whenever you use the same browser session. When a user logins to one of these application through Identity Server, there will be session created for that user inside the Identity Server and same session will be used whenever the same user (Same browser session) tries to login to any other registered application.